# Android - Problems with different sized layouts not working

Tags: android, layout, screen

I have a regular layout file : `Res/layout/test.xml`

And another layout for tablets : `Res/layout-large-land/test.xml`

This line is used in my Activity to declare the layout : `setContentView(R.layout.test);`

I'm using an Eclipse AVD emulator with the customer resolution of 1024x600 (Which according to the android site is a standard 7-inch tablet size). I've declared in my Manifest `<supports-screens>` with both normal and large as "true".

My problem is that the layout is always the original one, the different, larger layout never gets shown (even though the conditions would suggest it should?). Essentially the difference is the regular layout is a ListView and the large landscape one is a Table.

I've tried finding examples of how to get this online and in text books, but I can't find any that show what else to do. From what I've read, Android should make a conscious decision to pick the layout-large-land file over the regular layout one?

Thanks in advance for your help.

EDIT: I've been playing around with the layout, I've tried layout-land (which works fine), and changed the resolution of the emulator to be 854x480, still with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution might work for you:::

change res/layout-large-land to res/layout-xhdpi.

Comment: for 7 inch tablet we should use layout-xhdpi. try this and confirm

Comment: This appears to have some effect. However, it's vital that the large layout is only shown in landscape mode on a tablet, otherwise it should just be the default. If I try and use res/layout-xhdpi-land, this then becomes an error.